# The network connection was aborted by the local system in Windows 10 VPN

Tags: windows-10, vpn

I'm trying to connect to a VPN using Windows 10 built-in VPN, setting the `Server name or address`, `VPN Type` to `SSTP` (that is port 443, right?), a user and a password.

However I run into the error

> The network connection was aborted by the local system

Using another VPN client (FortiClient), setting the host, port, user, pass it works.

What is the difference? Why it isn't working on Windows 10's built-in VPN?

And if that is not enough information, how get I get more info? Are there log files?

Comment: Haven't tried the built in VPN, but SSTP is SSL/TLS which is port 443 as you correctly wrote, to answer your question.

Comment: Did you try to turn off the firewall?

Comment: Yes, I did try to turn off the firewall completely, even though it works using FortiClient client with the firewall on. But the same error occurs.